# como mostrar el valor seleccionado de un SELECT y mostrarlo en un DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

quisiera que al seleccionar un SELECT que contiene desde una base de datos APELLIDOS, me lo muestre en un DIV lo que seleccioné.(sería con la funcion ajax o jquery pero no me doy cuento como aplicarlo) Paso el código que tengo, me podrían ayudar por favor, les agradezco por su paciencia.

```
                             <div >                        
                              <p>Seleccione un apellido del siguiente menú:</p>
                              <p>Apellidos:
                              <select name="prontuarios">
                              <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
                         <?php
                          $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM t_prontuarios");
                          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo '<option 
                         value="'.$valores["id_prontuario"].'">'.$valores["fide"].'</option>';
                         echo $valores["id_prontuario"];
                         }
                        ?>
                       </select>
                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que registrar un listener para el evento `change` de tu select. Lo que hará esse listener es obtener el contenido de la opción que fue selecionada (`option:checked`). Después se reemplaza el contenido de la div por el contenido de la opción selecionada.

Seria algo como:

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const selectedOptionContent = event.target.querySelector('option:checked').textContent;
  
  document.querySelector('#selected-option-display').innerHTML = selectedOptionContent;
});
```

```html
<select name="prontuarios">
  <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
  <option value="1">Prontuario A</option>
  <option value="2">Prontuario B</option>
  <option value="3">Prontuario C</option>
  <option value="4">Prontuario D</option>
</select>

<div id="selected-option-display"> - </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto...!!!! muchas gracias funcionó...